How to use grpcurl with containerd.sock pull image？
I found the image.proto  file of containerd,
https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/api/services/images/v1/images.proto#L90
I can use the proto file to get a local image，
[root@master-18-86 ~]# ./grpcurl -d '{"name":"DaoCloud.redhat/registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.5"}'  -plaintext -proto image.proto -rpc-header containerd-namespace:k8s.io -unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock containerd.services.images.v1.Images/Get
{
  "image": {
    "name": "DaoCloud.redhat/registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.5",
    "labels": {
      "io.cri-containerd.image": "managed"
    },
    "target": {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
      "digest": "sha256:d7b036dcf284a11517256774c28d073d83617b65bdbbec35fafd29bb51872c7d",
      "size": "1960"
    },
    "createdAt": "2024-04-29T06:53:51.439354485Z",
    "updatedAt": "2024-04-29T06:53:51.447932784Z"
  }
}
[root@master-18-86 ~]#

but I didn't know how to use the grpcurl tool to download the image through the proto file，
[root@master-18-86 ~]# ./grpcurl -d '{"image":"DaoCloud.redhat/registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.5"}'  -plaintext -proto image.proto -rpc-header containerd-namespace:k8s.io -unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock containerd.services.images.v1.Images/Create
Error invoking method "containerd.services.images.v1.Images/Create": error getting request data: bad input: expecting start of JSON object: '{' ; instead got DaoCloud.redhat/registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.5

and i add name,
[root@master-18-86 ~]# ./grpcurl -d '{"image":{"name":"DaoCloud.redhat/registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.27.5"}}'  -plaintext -proto image.proto -rpc-header containerd-namespace:k8s.io -unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock containerd.services.images.v1.Images/Create
ERROR:
  Code: Unavailable
  Message: error reading from server: EOF

I want to mirror through proto pull, can anyone help me？
Or use api.proto pull?

I don't know. The containerd protos are curiously structured. The file is actually images.proto but this is a self-described metadata service. You can use this to e.g. Get a GetImageResponse which includes an Image.

The Image includes a .target.digest (sha256:....). This digest can be used with containerd.services.content.v1.Content/Read to get data which is a base 64 encoded manifest (?) and this includes the layers of the image. You can then get the layers' digests and each of these should be a binary blob corresponding to the layer.

./grpcurl  -plaintext -d '{"image":{"image":"{image_name}"}}'   -proto api.proto -rpc-header containerd-namespace:k8s.io -unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock runtime.v1.ImageService/PullImage

this works for me!
